# x/net/websocket getting cookie like *http.Request

Tags: go, websocket

i'm trying to get a cookie just like what *http.Request do ( `r.Cookie("cookie_key")` ), how i can achieve this without connection Upgrade (pure ws)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [this commit](https://github.com/golang/net/commit/0005f0a0c0c361196e53cd81bb023f8f563b85c) , actually you can just call

```
ws.Request().Cookie("guid")
```